# PNP Apply-ProvisioningTemplate - SharePoint List's field is skipped if of different type

Tags: sharepoint-online, splistitem, pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

I am currently using Azure Build and Release Pipelines to automate deployment to a testing environment. A PowerShell script is used to re-apply a template.xml file for the sites lists and libraries every time the release is deployed (in case the sites lists are updated with new fields or new lists are added to the site). the **issue** that I am facing is when a list's field changes type it is not being updated and is skipped.

for example:

List = Subscriptions

Column = SourcePermissions: of type "Choice" with display choice of "Checkboxes"

Update Column to = SourcePermissions: of type "Choice" with display choice of "Drop-Down Menu"

**I need to override SourcePermissions with the updated type that is in the template.xml file**

template.xml: below is the portion being skipped.

```
<Field Name="SourcePermissions" FromBaseType="FALSE" Type="Choice" DisplayName="SourcePermissions" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="Dropdown" FillInChoice="FALSE" ID="{487b3e3c-c13a-4e45-b0f8-f7ab75c91b78}" Version="3" StaticName="SourcePermissions" SourceID="{{listid:Subscriptions}}" ColName="nvarchar10" RowOrdinal="0" CustomFormatter="">
  <Default>All ITA</Default>
  <CHOICES>
    <CHOICE>All ITA</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>HCHB</CHOICE>
  </CHOICES>
</Field>
```

Portion of .ps1 file used to update site template:

```
#Apply provisioningtemplate 
Write-Host "Started applying template"
#set culture in case devops agent is running on a different culture
Set-Culture -CultureInfo en-us
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "$env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY/_CI/sharepoint/template.xml" -Connection $newSiteConnection
Write-Host "Finished applying template"
```

the warning recieved:
[image]

there is no error when applying the template just this message.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if converting a field from a multi choice (checkboxes) to a single choice (drop down) is even supported. If the list has existing data, what do you expect would happen to it? Those field values are represented differently internally.

Log an issue on the PnP github repo and confirm what you're trying to do is supported.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. I would expect the existing data to be wiped if the field type changed. I will log this issue in the repo suggested. Thanks.